# Как сделать button в виде треугольника в WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

Нашел множество примеров как сделать круглые кнопки, но не одного решения о том как сделать в виде треугольника. Возможно ли это, или лучше использовать изображение для этой цели?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А можете, пожалуйста, приложить картинку того, какую именно вам нужно получить кнопку?

Comment: Обычный треугольник )))

Comment: @МаксимШалашов Ага, сейчас сделаю треугольник, а вы скажете, что не такой, недостаточно обычный:)

Comment: Вадим тут важно не как он выглядит, а принцип возможно это сделать или нет. Поправить его и сделать вверх, вниз, вправо, влево направленный думаю смогу сделать если пойму принцип создание подобных кнопок.

Comment: @МаксимШалашов Вам помог мой ответ или требуется что-то доработать?

Comment: Как одно из решений данной задачи, как раз трудность появилась в том что нужно эмитировать поведение границ данного треугольника как у button. Ну это уже из разряда перфекционизма ))

Comment: @МаксимШалашов А вы через собачку пишите комментарии, иначе я уведомления не получаю о сообщении.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Чтобы кнопка была действительно треугольной, необходимо переопределить ее шаблон.

Чтобы не писать шаблон с нуля полностью, я возьму за основу стандартный, для этого в Visual Studio в дизайнере щелкаем правой по кнопке и выбираем <kbd>Edit Template</kbd>-<kbd>Edit a Copy...</kbd> и вводим желаемое название шаблона и выбираем место его расположения (можно просто нажать OK и переместить/переименовать позже вручную).

Студия добавит стандартный шаблон кнопки, редактируем его: ищем `<Setter Property="Template">` у меня там такой шаблон:

```
<Border x:Name="border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
    <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" Focusable="False" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
</Border>
```

В другой ОС он может отличаться, правим его:

```
<Path Name="border" Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" Data="M12,24 L36,0 L36,48 Z" Width="48"/>
```

Кнопка будет простая и не будет уметь содержать контент, поэтому одного `Path` достаточно.

Смотрим теперь те места, что подчеркнуты синим, наименования свойств у `Border` и `Path` отличаются, поэтому надо эти места поправить, кисть для границы называется `Stroke` (вместо `BorderBrush`), а кисть для заливки — `Fill` (вместо `Background`). Контента нет, поэтому строчку `<Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="contentPresenter" Value="{StaticResource Button.Disabled.Foreground}"/>` удаляю полностью.

Триггеры поправлены, синих подчеркиваний не должно остаться, дизайнер должен заработать, можно запустить и проект. Кнопка, в принципе, уже функционирует нормально, но если с помощью клавиши <kbd>Tab</kbd> установить на нее фокус, то мы увидим, что он прямоугольный. За фокус отвечает свойство `FocusVisualStyle`, видим в стиле, что он устанавливается так: `<Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource FocusVisual}"/>`, т.е. необходимо отредактировать также ресурс `FocusVisual`, там сейчас находится `Rectangle`, мы возьмем наш уже готовый `Path`, но без заливки и с прерывистой границей (как и было у `Rectangle`):

```
<Path Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" StrokeThickness="1" StrokeDashArray="1 2" Data="M12,24 L36,0 L36,48 Z" Width="48"/>
```

Видим, что геометрия `Path` повторяется дважды, чтобы избежать дублирования, вынесем ее отдельным ресурсом:

```
<StreamGeometry x:Key="Geometry">M12,24 L36,0 L36,48 Z</StreamGeometry>
```

Тогда в `Path` достаточно будет указать `Data="{StaticResource Geometry}"`

Ну и напоследок можно поудалять ненужные сеттеры из стиля, которые касаются контента.

Еще, для того, чтобы иметь возможность получить кнопки со стрелками еще и вниз/вверх/вправо, добавим в ресурсы следующие трансформации:

```
<RotateTransform x:Key="Rotate90" CenterX="24" CenterY="24" Angle="90"/>
<RotateTransform x:Key="Rotate180" CenterX="24" CenterY="24" Angle="180"/>
<RotateTransform x:Key="Rotate270" CenterX="24" CenterY="24" Angle="270"/>
```

В итоге весь пример целиком выглядит следующим образом:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <StreamGeometry x:Key="Geometry">M12,24 L36,0 L36,48 Z</StreamGeometry>
    <Style x:Key="FocusVisual">
        <Setter Property="Control.Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Path Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" StrokeThickness="1" StrokeDashArray="1 2" Data="{StaticResource Geometry}" Width="48"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Static.Background" Color="#FFDDDDDD"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Static.Border" Color="#FF707070"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.MouseOver.Background" Color="#FFBEE6FD"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.MouseOver.Border" Color="#FF3C7FB1"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Pressed.Background" Color="#FFC4E5F6"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Pressed.Border" Color="#FF2C628B"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Disabled.Background" Color="#FFF4F4F4"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Disabled.Border" Color="#FFADB2B5"/>
    <Style x:Key="TriangleButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource FocusVisual}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource Button.Static.Background}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource Button.Static.Border}"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Path Name="border" Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" Data="{StaticResource Geometry}" Width="48"/>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsDefaulted" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="border" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.MouseOver.Background}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.MouseOver.Border}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.Pressed.Background}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.Pressed.Border}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.Disabled.Background}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.Disabled.Border}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <RotateTransform x:Key="Rotate090" CenterX="24" CenterY="24" Angle="090"/>
    <RotateTransform x:Key="Rotate180" CenterX="24" CenterY="24" Angle="180"/>
    <RotateTransform x:Key="Rotate270" CenterX="24" CenterY="24" Angle="270"/>
</Window.Resources>

<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    <Button Style="{DynamicResource TriangleButtonStyle}"/>
    <Button Style="{DynamicResource TriangleButtonStyle}" RenderTransform="{StaticResource Rotate090}"/>
    <Button Style="{DynamicResource TriangleButtonStyle}" RenderTransform="{StaticResource Rotate180}"/>
    <Button Style="{DynamicResource TriangleButtonStyle}" RenderTransform="{StaticResource Rotate270}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Единственное бы значение `Data` для `Path` сделать, чтобы не дублировалось, а так очень хорошо. Также не совсем понятно как именно применять те же стили для кнопок разных направлений.

Comment: Ну это уже мелочи, надеюсь, ТС справится с этим самостоятельно. А разные направления — да хоть как у вас через `RotateTransform` (которые тоже можно положить в ресурсы и потом задавать самой кнопке, типа `RenderTransform="{StaticResource Rotate90}"`)

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, дополнил ответ.

Comment: Спасибо, выглядит круто! Небольшой вопрос-замечение: а не является ли уставовка свойств `CenterX="24" CenterY="24"` во-первых негибким, так как мы можем захотеть увеличивать и уменьшать кнопки (я полагаю, что с изменением размера начнутся проблемы, но я могу ошибаться), во-вторых дублированием в каждом стиле? Может лучше самой копке установить `RenderTransformOrigin="0.5, 0.5"?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, этот вариант кнопки немасштабируем. Можно, конечно, Path поместить во ViewBox, но, как известно, он масштабирует и толщину линий, что при большом масштабе будет смотреться нехорошо. По идее надо писать конвертер для масштаба и рисовать геометрию с его использованием. По поводу `RenderTransformOrigin` скорее всего вы правы, надо попробовать и с ним.

Comment: Масштабирования всё-таки можно достичь: 1) надо заменять `CenterX="24"` и `CenterY="24"` на `RenderTransformOrigin="0.5, 0.5"`. 2) Чтобы кнопки масштабировались задайте `Path` значение `Stretch="Uniform"`. 3) В `Path` для `FocusVisual` и `Button` надо удалить `Width="48"`.

Answer (score 2):

Вам надо просто создать иконку в векторном стиле с помощью `Path` и удалить границы и фон с кнопки (для этого стиль кнопки основываем на `{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}`, так как с помощью этого стиля удаляются границы и фон кнопки).

В итоге XAML окна (к примеру, `MainWindow.xaml`):

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <Button Style="{StaticResource ArrowButtonStyle}">
        <Path Style="{StaticResource ArrowIconButtonStyle}" />
    </Button>

    <Button Style="{StaticResource ArrowButtonStyle}">
        <Path Style="{StaticResource ArrowIconButtonStyle}">
            <Path.RenderTransform>
                <RotateTransform Angle="90" />
            </Path.RenderTransform>
        </Path>
    </Button>

    <Button Style="{StaticResource ArrowButtonStyle}">
        <Path Style="{StaticResource ArrowIconButtonStyle}">
            <Path.RenderTransform>
                <RotateTransform Angle="180" />
            </Path.RenderTransform>
        </Path>
    </Button>

    <Button Style="{StaticResource ArrowButtonStyle}">
        <Path Style="{StaticResource ArrowIconButtonStyle}">
            <Path.RenderTransform>
                <RotateTransform Angle="-90" />
            </Path.RenderTransform>
        </Path>
    </Button>
</StackPanel>
```

Стили (к примеру, в `App.xaml`):

```
<Style x:Key="ArrowButtonStyle" TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}">
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5" />
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="100" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="100" />
</Style>
<Style x:Key="ArrowIconButtonStyle" TargetType="Path">
    <Setter Property="Data" Value="F1 M 287.328,237.333L 319.344,255.818L 319.344,218.849L 287.328,237.333 Z " />
    <Setter Property="Fill" Value="#00a8f3" />
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="40" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="80" />
    <Setter Property="Stretch" Value="Fill" />
    <Setter Property="RenderTransformOrigin" Value="0.5, 0.5" />
</Style>
```

В итоге получаем разные стрелки:

[image: стрелочные кнопки]

---

Если эти кнопки надо переиспользовать много раз, то можно и свойство `RenderTransform` положить в отдельные стили для каждого направления стрелки.

`MainWindow.xaml`

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <Button Style="{StaticResource ArrowButtonStyle}">
        <Path Style="{StaticResource ArrowLeftIconButtonStyle}" />
    </Button>

    <Button Style="{StaticResource ArrowButtonStyle}">
        <Path Style="{StaticResource ArrowTopIconButtonStyle}" />
    </Button>

    <Button Style="{StaticResource ArrowButtonStyle}">
        <Path Style="{StaticResource ArrowRightIconButtonStyle}" />
    </Button>

    <Button Style="{StaticResource ArrowButtonStyle}">
        <Path Style="{StaticResource ArrowBottomIconButtonStyle}" />
    </Button>
</StackPanel>
```

`App.xaml`

```
<Style x:Key="ArrowButtonStyle" TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}">
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5" />
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="100" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="100" />
</Style>
<Style x:Key="ArrowIconButtonStyle" TargetType="Path">
    <Setter Property="Data" Value="F1 M 287.328,237.333L 319.344,255.818L 319.344,218.849L 287.328,237.333 Z " />
    <Setter Property="Fill" Value="#00a8f3" />
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="40" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="80" />
    <Setter Property="Stretch" Value="Fill" />
    <Setter Property="RenderTransformOrigin" Value="0.5, 0.5" />
</Style>
<Style x:Key="ArrowLeftIconButtonStyle" TargetType="Path" BasedOn="{StaticResource ArrowIconButtonStyle}">
</Style>
<Style x:Key="ArrowRightIconButtonStyle" TargetType="Path" BasedOn="{StaticResource ArrowIconButtonStyle}">
    <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
        <Setter.Value>
            <RotateTransform Angle="180" />
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
<Style x:Key="ArrowTopIconButtonStyle" TargetType="Path" BasedOn="{StaticResource ArrowIconButtonStyle}">
    <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
        <Setter.Value>
            <RotateTransform Angle="90" />
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
<Style x:Key="ArrowBottomIconButtonStyle" TargetType="Path" BasedOn="{StaticResource ArrowIconButtonStyle}">
    <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
        <Setter.Value>
            <RotateTransform Angle="-90" />
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: А почему именно от `ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey`?

Comment: @АндрейNOP Просто потому что удаляются фон и границы с помощью этого стиля. Сейчас внесу это в ответ.

Comment: На самом деле не удаляются, а становятся невидимыми, но при наведении курсора или при получении фокуса видно что кнопка не треугольная

Comment: @АндрейNOP Да, всё именно так, как вы и описали. Меня удовлетворяет данное поведение. Конечно, можно чтобы кнопка была действительно треугольной, но лично я не вижу в этом смысла и удобства со стороны пользователя.