# WPF кнопка ломаной формы

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Хочу сделать кнопку нестандартной формы, но никак не могу сообразить.
Красная граница, это форма большой кнопки

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если применить `Grid.ColumnSpan`, то он распространится на всю колонку и закроет маленькую кнопку.
Как можно сделать такую кнопку?
Заранее спаисибо!

Comment: Пробуйте через Path. Сможете сделать объект любой формы. потом повесить любое событие на него.
`
  <Path Stroke="Black">
    <Path.Data>
        <LineGeometry StartPoint="100,30" EndPoint="10,20" />
        <LineGeometry StartPoint="100,30" EndPoint="10,40" />
        <LineGeometry StartPoint="100,30" EndPoint="40,40" />
        <LineGeometry StartPoint="100,30" EndPoint="40,80" />
        <LineGeometry StartPoint="100,30" EndPoint="120,80" />
         .....
    </Path.Data>
</Path>
`

Comment: Возможный дубликат: [Как сделать button в виде треугольника в WPF?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/846818/218063)

Comment: Да, взял за основу тот ваш ответ. Спасибо